# Creating a log file counter

Tags: linux, perl

New to the syntax of perl, trying to set up a counter that counts the number of time a failed password occurs from a log file, and than print out the total number to console.  I get a lot of numbers printed to the screen, instead of just one total at the end.  Any thoughts or directions would be helpful.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$count = 0;

open (MYFILE, 'auth.log');
while (my $line = <MYFILE>){
if ($line =~ /Failed password/){
$count++;
}
print $count;
#print "$line\n" if $line =~ /Failed password/;
#this was a print test to see if it would only print the failed password strings in the file.    
}
close (MYFILE);
```

Comment: Just move your brace above `print $count;`.  You print the count throughout the entire log reading.  Indentation helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the `print $count` outside of the `while` loop.

You also should check the return code of the `open` our else you won't know if the file is missing or unopenable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $count = 0;

open (my $fh, '<', 'auth.log') or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>){
    if ($line =~ /Failed password/){
        $count++;
    }
}
close $fh;
print $count;
```

Finally, here's another way to do it from the command line:

```
grep -c 'Failed password' auth.log
```

Comment: Use three argument open :).

Comment: Done, and lexical filehandles.

Comment: i have not seen the use warnings and use strict yet, or the die $!, is this more advance perl syntax?  I would like to know more about what they do?  I am intrigued. :)

Comment: No, they are not advanced at all.  They are standard practice these days.  Take a look at http://perl101.org/ for other standard practices that you should know.